# how to uninstall mist permanently for Mac

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

my mist is not syncing in private network and it did not show the ethers. so I need to uninstall Mist permanently and  again I want to install .But when I install the mist it shows the older mist .

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely your blockchain not syncing, try 
1) `delete $home/Libary/Ethereum/chaindata` this should wipe out the blockchain itself and let you sync from scratch. 
2) `delete the entire $home/Libary/Ethereum` folder (backup your keystore folder, which is your wallets before deleting, very important!!) 
3) Try `geth removedb` to remove the blockchain and state databases.

Comment: I just did the same as you mentioned but still it shows me the previous mist and also it is not working when I connect to private network and I opened mist by using terminal and mist shows an error  couldn't connect to the node. Retry the connections